# Creating Auto Number field with preceding number of 0's?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

Scenario: I have a table with a (int4) field 'pg_recordid' that has newly inserted records auto-increment the new record id using this macro after running 'SERIAL' in the field (in Navicat)

`nextval('raw_casper_pg_recordid_seq'::regclass)`

The current output for the first record: `1`

Is there a method to set the macro so the Auto numbers have the entire number length filled with 0's for unused digits? example: `000001`

Comment: You could use a view with an added column, computed from the serial and padded with 0s.

Comment: Don't store the zeros, just add them when _displaying_ them (e.g. by using `to_char()` to format the number.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this in Navicat or in the database? I don't know about Navicat but PostgreSQL certainly doesn't have "macros".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks! Is this a function I can call on the same field, or do I have to create a new postgres field and call the function on the original field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without getting into a technical argument, once you start getting fussy about the display of a number, it is no longer just a number. (Mathematically, we refer to a **number** as its value, while its display is referred to a **numeral**).

Why is this important? What you are asking for is not actually a number, but some way of displaying it. The short answer is that you will need to convert it to a string.

If you want to zero-pad a number, you use a combination of string operations:

- `::char` will convert a value to a string
- `lpad(string,length,padding)` will left-pad a string with the given padding.

Combining the two you get:

```
select lpad(id::char,4,'0'), …
from …;
```

where `id` is presumed to be your auto-numbered column.

Comment: Solid answer. Stick around.

Comment: Thanks! I came to a similar conclusion and decided that I liked the benefits of the record id as an integer just fine